# web link management - php vs database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, memory

I am new at web development, and I have started to work on a small website just recently. Now the problem is, that since it is my first time, I move my pages a lot on the server, because of which I have to keep updating all the other pages that link to it. So, I was thinking of a dynamic way of linking the pages, so that I don't have to update at several places, but only at one.

How it is going to work is that,

- there is going to be a separate database kind of thing that will contain all the webpages' updated address, and a unique key to identify them. eg. page12345 = "/about/us.php"
- and anywhere where I want to include a link to the page, instead of typing `<a href="/about/us/php">..</a>`, I'll have to type something like `<a href="<?php echo $arr['page12345'] ?>">..</a>`, or something like that

This method will also enable me to assign tags/categories to pages, and, or add other properties to them. And, I'll probably also use it for media files as well later.

Now, the thing is, I can think of only two ways to do so, one is using an array in PHP, and other is using MySQL database. The array will probably be too much to handle when the site grows and there are, like thousands of pages, on ther other hand, MySQL database will probably prove to be slower, and at the same time more of a hassle.

So what is it that you suggest? Which will be more efficient. Or is there a better way, I am open to any other ideas that you may have.

Comment: "MySQL will prove to be slower" - not unless you scale to millions of pages, and even then, with the right hardware and architecture, you'll still be fine. MySQL is very capable for what you want.

Comment: Where you have page sections containing repeated information (e.g. links in a menu) then centralise them in one file and `include()` it at the appropriate point.

Comment: Of course, you can do all the above with WordPress, so don't reinvent the wheel unless you really need to.

Comment: @halfer so should I prefer MySQL to array in PHP,  also, what you mentioned in the second comment is something that I am already using, but only for the navigation menu, as they need to be included in every page,  I have never used wordpress, and also i'd prefer not to use a CMS,(i have never used one but believe they might limit things, specially on the back-end, if it's not true, please do correct me)

Comment: I have to use a lot of PHP and database queries, as well as some front end scripting

Comment: Should you prefer a database to PHP? Either will work. I suggest a database, since the "About us" page sounds like you are managing editable content, and a database is the usual choice here. However, as @deceze points out in an answer, a router will usually use an array or a flat file of some kind, which is the common way to do it in an application (where the "pages" are under the control of a developer rather than a writer/editor).

Comment: @halfer  thanks to your insight and deceze's answer, I think I know what I want to use, I use a MySQL database, along with some php functions, and probably face no problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to manage that is to not worry about URLs manually at all and leave up to a *router*. In the end, URLs are just a technical implementation detail of the HTTP protocol. What you really want to do is identify specific pages/actions uniquely. Have a look at any reverse-routing capable router; here the [Symfony implementation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls-from-a-template):

```
blog_show:
    path:     /blog/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: 'BlogController::showAction' }
```

```
<a href="{{ path('blog_show', {'slug': 'my-blog-post'}) }}">Read this blog post.</a>
```

This is admittedly a very high level abstraction, using YAML for specifying routes and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org) for templating with a custom defined function. However, it hopefully demonstrates the goal: don't worry about URLs much at all in your actual links. You need to have *one* canonical place where URLs are defined (the `path` in the above example), everywhere else you just refer to your target page by name (`blog_show` here). If you need to move URLs around, there's exactly one place where you need to do so. The thing in the middle that makes this work is the router.

Comment: though this isn't exactly what I wanted, but reading this has given me an idea, which i believe should do the trick, thanks